# Excel-addin: Best way to clone "Range" object

Tags: office-js

Suppose we obtain a certain range with getRange call (OrigRange). What's the best way to clone this range (including all formatting)?  I would like to manipulate, for instance, font, color and update the worksheet. But, I need to keep the original range. Simple variable assignment does not work. It updates the OrigRange as well.

var newRange = OrigRange 
newRange.format.fill.color = "blue"

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you mean by "clone", and "keeping the original range"?  Are you saying that you'd like to get "A3:B5", and copy all of its values, fonts, colors, etc. to "E3:F5"?  Or do you mean something else?...

Comment: Eventually I want to "undo" behavior. Let's say have "A3:B5" as the original. function A updates only color, function B updates only font, etc. And then, "undo" function bring the original back.